# Sphinx raises warnings for class derived from IntEnum - can I do something about it?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

As the title says. The warnings are:

```
docstring of liesel.goose.EpochType.from_bytes:9: WARNING: Inline interpreted text or phrase reference start-string without end-string.
docstring of liesel.goose.EpochType.to_bytes:8: WARNING: Inline interpreted text or phrase reference start-string without end-string.
```

I am using Sphinx version `7.2.6`.

My investigation yielded the following:

The class `EpochType` is derived from [`enum.IntEnum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.IntEnum). IntEnum is derived partly from `int` ([source code on GitHub](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b905fad83819ec9102ecfb97e3d8ab0aaddd9784/Lib/enum.py#L1315)).

As far as I can see, the methods [`from_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes) and [`to_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) originate from the corresponding methods on `int`.

I do not understand why sphinx is throwing this warning and/or what I can do about it.

Comment: This is interesting, can you include a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Please edit the question to include any necessary source code that allows reproducing the problem by copy-pasting.

Comment: I can reproduce the warnings, but I cannot explain them. The docstrings for `to_bytes` and `from_bytes` that get included in the output are found here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/clinic/longobject.c.h#L255..

Comment: I think the problem is the reference to `sys.byteorder` in the docstrings. Instead of a trailing backtick, there is a backslash followed by an apostrophe (`\`sys.byteorder\'`).